# View Model Patterns and usage in ASP.NET MVC3 (Also, using EF 4.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have been searching for an answer to this question for days and it is driving me insane. Currently I am working on a project using ASP.NET MVC 3 and am trying to utilize a ViewModel per controller approach as has been suggested by so many articles and tutorials I have checked out. To better illistrate what I am asking I will outline below:

Lets say I have a pretty simple and straight forward model. Users, Customers, Addresses, Phone Numbers, Orders, Products, Categories, etc... When a user registers for a new account on my site I would like to:
1) create an account for them (this is just an account id, customer type)
2) Add their customer demographic data to Customers
3) Add N-addresses and address types
4) Add N-phone numbers with type as well.

As far as I have got is deciding that I need a RegisterCustomerForRegistrationControllerViewModel. My predicament is what does this model look like? I am trying to be as DRY as possible yet when implementing this pattern I seem to repeat myself at each turn. At what level do I put DataAnnotations for validation? So do I simply new up a new Customer() even if I only want to use one property from the class in a given ViewModel?

I'm not even confident at this point that this is a correct assumption. There seems to be so much opinion on the topic yet so few concrete examples of implementation. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction and maybe present some code snippets along the way... I hope this is all clear enough and if not please feel free to ask follow up questions.

Again, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeating simple properties across two distinct layers of an application is not a violation of DRY. Its just good design.

DataAnnotations go on ViewModels.

ViewModel will look something like

```
public class RegisterCustomerViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AddressViewModels> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumberViewModel> PhoneNumbers { get; set; |

}
```

Comment: That's all well and good, but now you've got business logic in the UI layer.  Your business layer needs to also enforce the Name Required rule, or you'll lose it when you throw away your MVC UI for whatever UI is next.

Comment: @Andy: You should perform validation at every level in your application. I don't think @jfar was implying otherwise.

Comment: @Andy, thats not business logic, thats input sanitation which you are required to do in the UI level anyway.  DataAnnotations attributes can be used in another UI layer.  There is no limitation there and are designed for that purpose.

Comment: I think it's business logic.  Would you ever allow someone to register without entering thier name?  Who makes that call?  Probably the business, and its a rule you'd want to keep regardless of UI.  Yes, you can reuse DataAnnotations in other layers, but you have to figure out how to run them yourself.  I'm not aware of any engine that takes care of that for you.  Also, unless you want your business layer to see your VM (which I personally don't), you'll have to repeat the annotation on your business model, in other words, you need to repeat it in two places or you'll have problems.

Comment: @jfar Hmmmm that is interesting. It never even crossed my mind that I would need to create classes for Address or PhoneNumber view models to be included inside of the ViewModel. I would have just used the main class. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Andy this is the problem I have been having. If I apply (most) DataAnnoations at multiple levels it seems to me that there is a lot of room for error in the future. Seems pretty easy to make changes in 4/5 places and that last place could cause a pretty nasty bug.

Comment: @Clayton Bench: This is why writing unit tests on each level is important ;)

Comment: @Andy - So are you suggesting you are better off creating your own validation engine and bubbling up all validation errors so your UI layer therefore coupling business logic to UI just so you have DRY?  Thats some serious coupling right there.

Comment: @Andy, So for more context, you cannot trust user input, but you should be able to trust code that calls your business layer.  So if Name is really important for address reasons then I may validate again but usually you should be able to trust any input that made it past UI validation.  I'm not saying don't validate in two places if its important just have to make trade off for the sake of not over-coding something.

Comment: @Jfar:  No, there are frameworks for building business objects, which mostly eliminate the need for separate VMs.  They aren't tied to any particular UI technology, and will pick up your data annonations as well.

Comment: @Andy, I get your point of view now.  Rather couple and make the core of your application dependent on a 3rd party framework than simply separate some concerns and duplicate some trivial logic.  Overzealous use of DRY gets you into bad situations.

Comment: @Jfar: In this case the business logic is trival, but in most real applications it gets much more hairier than that.  I fail to see the problem with building business libraries ontop of business library framework. You want MVC, you use a framework. MVVM, the same. DAL, you build on a framework... but for some reason people refuse to use a framework for a business layer. The result is lots of extra classes, lots more duplication of rules everywhere. The problem is DAL/UI technologies change far more often than business rules, and not using a framework makes UI more expensive to throw away.

Comment: @Jfar:  Overzealous separation of concerns also gets you into bad situtations, and hurt maintainablity (read:  more expensive).

Comment: @jfar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1384/discussion-between-andy-and-jfar)

Comment: @Andy - No thanks on the chat.  I think you over estimate the cost of keeping two simple properties in synch.  Its not like the FirstName field disappears from the application.  Check out the DDD concept of bounded contexts and maybe you may understand my point better.  Basing your core code around a business object framework is a really strange suggestion from somebody who wants to keep UI projects distinct.  You can't just pull CSLA out of your project once you've started using...

Comment: @Jfar:  I don't think so, I've done both.  We've been doing DDD, and its been far more complex to maintain than Csla-based projects I've worked on, and plenty of bugs have been logged b/c the two objects are not kept in sync, among other problems.  I fail to understand the importance of pulling out Csla (or other similar frameworks), when you end up re-implementing much of the functionality it would have provided.  I've yet to hear a good reason for NOT using such a framework.  Its become this zealot thing, "our BOs MUST be POCO."

Answer (score 1):

Just like jfar, I would take a simple approache: one view, one view model with DataAnnotations.

That being said... I know how you feel (not confident) and I understand because I've been through that myself. My conclusions: unless you consider your web application to require the overhead of so many layers, principles and patterns, keep it simple. I believe that there is no perfect architecture. There's just what works and there's overhead. Sometime, what works is indeed complexe. Ask yourself if you need that complexity.

Take my first sentence as an answer to your question and the rest as my humble opinion.